# fileshare not working, windows 10

Tags: network-share, windows-10, file-sharing, server-message-block

I can't share files from some windows 10 computers. Revision doesn't matter.

port 445 is listening:

TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    192.168.0.27:54220      DC-IP-addr:445          ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4

I can telnet localhost 445

I can't telnet my-ip 445

It means I can't telnet to my computer from my computer by ip address. Something is blocking it on interface. 139 port is opened on interface and can be telneted.

All antivirus software disabled. Firewall, defender disabled.

File and Printer Sharing service reinstalled from network adapter settings.

Enabling disabling SMBv1, SMBv2 on client and host -> doesn't help.

"Function Discovery Provider Host" and "Function Discovery Resource Publication" both running on client and host.

NetBios enabled on network adapter, however it doesn't work in windows 10. I can't nbtstat -a ip-address.